# Using amp-img tag for gif animations

Tags: html, seo, amp-html, amp-img

There is `<amp-anim>` tag for gif animations.
But I found that `<amp-img>` tag can show gif animations.
I know `<amp-anim>` tag can set a placeholder, but I don't need it.
And I found no defference any more.
So, my question is "Is there problem to use `<amp-img>` tag for gif animations?"

Open https://ampbyexample.com/playground/ and paste the html code below, if you want to check how work `<amp-img>` tag and `<amp-anim>` tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-anim" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-anim-0.1.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-anim/">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>amp-anim supports gif animation</h2>
  <amp-anim width="245" height="300" src="/img/gopher.gif" alt="an animation"
            attribution="The Go gopher was designed by Reneee French and is licensed under CC 3.0 attributions.">
  </amp-anim>

  <h2>amp-img also supports gif animation</h2>
  <amp-img width="245" height="300" src="/img/gopher.gif" alt="an animation"
            attribution="The Go gopher was designed by Reneee French and is licensed under CC 3.0 attributions.">
  </amp-img>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between `amp-anim` and `amp-img` is [performance: `amp-anim` is able to reduce CPU usage when the animation is off-screen](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/8116#issuecomment-287202023).

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the [amp-anim docs](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/media/amp-anim) that amp-anim is an extended version of `amp-img` in that it provides additional functionality with the GIF animations specifically in mind. As long as `amp-img` is working for you then by all means use it.

> The amp-anim component is very similar to the amp-img element, and
>   provides additional functionality to manage loading and playing of
>   animated images such as GIFs.